# how to add path with module to python?

Tags: python, v8, gyp

I try to build V8 javascript engine.
When I try to invoke the command `python build/git_v8`, I get error:

```
File build/gyp_v8, line 48 in < module >
     import gyp
ImportError: No module named GYP
```

How I can tell python where search GYP module and what is the correct path to the module in the folder GYP?

My version of python is 2.6.2.2, recommended in build instructions.

Comment: just do `pip install pyv8`

Comment: see https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Where to call pip install pyv8?

Comment: from your terminal window ... you need setuptools if you dont already have it...

Comment: @JoranBeasley ah, didn't knew pip and it wasn't installed. sadly, this was no solution for me. thanks anyway

Comment: it might be different versions of python installed and full path specified in py file at `#!/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, the module gyp.py is not in the search path of modules (sys.path). sys.path is an array variable in sys module which contains all known paths of the modules. You can add the directory containing the module gyp.py manually by either of these methods:

1. set via PYTHONPATH environment variable (see http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=path#envvar-PYTHONPATH)
2. Add the path manually within your python script prior to importing gyp. For example, if the directory containing this module is /home/you/gyp:

```py
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/you/gyp')

import gyp
#--------- That's it ------------
```

You can check if this path already exists using the debug lines

```
import sys
print(sys.path) # version python 3.2
```

or

```
print sys.path # version python 2.7
```

Answer (score 8):

Install the module will be fine.

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp
cd gyp
sudo ./setup.py install
```

enjoy it.

Comment: or just `easy_install -U gyp`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment -- but as @chrylis reported above -- links change. The new link for git'ing gyp is: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp.git if anyone else is hunting. Other than that -- the installation worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to install the module, **notice the google source url has changed**.

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/external/gyp
cd gyp
sudo ./setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

`Gyp` is a custom build tool by Google. The instructions at https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP should be helpful.

Go to the root of the V8 checkout or source directory, and run

`svn co http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk build/gyp`